# BackgroundDownloader and "Only up to 50 groups can be configured"

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-metro

I have a WinRT app (Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1). I use the `BackgroundDownloader` to download files in groups.

I use the groups to download audiobooks, so all the track of an audiobook are download in one group and can be cancelled at once. The download in each group are download in serial (not in parallel) so the user can start listening to an audiobook from the start.

I use a code like this to create the downloads:

```
var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader
{
    TransferGroup = BackgroundTransferGroup.CreateGroup(groupKey),
};

var download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);

download.TransferGroup.TransferBehavior = BackgroundTransferBehavior.Serialized;
```

The problem is that when the user initiates more then 50 download, the

```
download.TransferGroup.TransferBehavior = BackgroundTransferBehavior.Serialized;
```

line of code throws an `Only up to 50 groups can be configured` exception.

The exception, probably an `BackgroundDownloader` limitation (with no info about this on MSDN of course) would be fine, if it would be a limit to have 50 running download groups.

The problem is, that the exception also occurs when downloads finish.

An example: the user initiates 49 downloads, all of the finish successfully. Then the user initiates 1 more download, everything is ok. Then the user initiates 1 more download and this exception is thrown. Although there are not 50 download groups already running. Just 50 download groups have been created since the star of the app.

Is there a way to "remove" the groups when they are finished? Do I have to deals with the groups after they are download manually? Is is a WinRT bug (I would not be surprised)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I know no way to delete finished BackgroundTransferGroup.
Also, as it says on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransfergroup.aspx):

> Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 support a maximum of 50 unique transfer groups for the entire system. So an app should reuse a unique ID or a small number of unique IDs for all transfer groups created by the app. If more than 50 transfer groups are created on the system, the app will get in an unrecoverable state.

Although MS does not restrict the number of groups for one app (beyond the system limit), this means that one has to be careful about how many groups they create and find an acceptable mechanism to reuse them.

Given the limitations, you might find yourself limiting maximum number of concurrent downloads (meaning groups) occurring simultaneously, or grouping the downloads to one big app group, or not grouping them at all.

Comment: this sucks .. one big groups / no groups is not acceptable for me because of the audiobook use case descripbed .. reusing groups is really asking for trouble

Comment: Reusing groups (keep track of your group names) is the only available solution at this moment.